# Cancel partial derivative in fraction

Tags: calculus

> The question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942579/hamilton-jacobi-bellman-first-order-condition-and-derivative-of-value-function).

Let $f(x,y) = xy$ and $g(x,y) = f(x,y)^2 = x^2y^2$.
Now consider the fraction of partial derivatives
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} = \frac{2xy^2}{y} = 2xy
\end{align}

I was wondering if I can cancel $\partial x$ in the fraction, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial f} = \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial f} = 2f = 2xy. 
\end{align}

- Is this some general principle or coincidence?

Comment: Someone calls it chain rule

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431157/why-is-the-cancellation-of-partial-derivatives-like-fractions-justified-in-this) is another example. I mean you cannot cancel the partial derivative sign in principle can you?

Comment: The chain rule says that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}={\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}} \frac{\partial g}{\partial f} $ so your equation is perfectly valid (if you omit to say you are canceling anything).

Comment: What if $f$ and $g$ are not transformations of each other, say, $g = x^2/2$ and $f = x + y$?

Comment: Then you have no chain rule and the equation is not valid. Anyway, in your example, you can still say $g=(f-y)^2/2$ and treat $y$ as a constant.

Comment: These answers are so snarky, I'm sorry OP. I'd like to know the answer as well, since cancelling derivatives is NOT always allowed. (For example, in @user115350 's answer, if you cancel back the dx and dy's, you get dg/df = 2 dg/df.)

Answer (score -1):

This is not by accident. As N74 said, this is chain rule. So $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial f}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial f}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial f}=\frac{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}+\frac{\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}$$

Comment: Well, your $\partial g/\partial f = 4xy$ is different though since you included $\partial y$. Now I'm confused.